# how to convert the first output in second output in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have this javascript variable with this content: i must convert the "," in "newline" to have multiple lines. I am thinking about regExp,but i don't know how to manage it.

```
var output= "Query Response #1:,(0008,0005) CS ssxssx,(00,00) DA dsdww,(w,e) TM dww,(20)sxs";
```

i would want to have  an output of this type:

```
Query Response #1:
(0008,0005) CS ssxssx
(00,00) DA dsdww
(w,e) TM dww
(20)sxs
```

Does anyone have any ideas to fix this problem? Thanks

this is the regExp that matches those "," but i don't know how to reproduce the desidere output

```
var regex_virgola= /\,\(/gm;
```

```
var regex_virgola= /\,\(/gm;
regex_virgola= regex_virgola.toString();

function getIndexes(searchStr, str) {
    var searchStrLen = searchStr.length;
    if (searchStrLen == 0) {
        return [];
    }
    var startIndex = 0, index, indices = [];
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
    while ((index = str.indexOf(searchStr, startIndex)) > -1) {
        indices.push(index);
        startIndex = index + searchStrLen;
    }
    return indices;
}

var Indici  = getIndexes(regex_virgola, output);
console.log('IndiciVirgola:'+ Indici);
```

BUT IN CONSOLE IT GIVES TO ME EMPTY STRUCTURE

Comment: Can you change format? Because now some of `,` are replaced and some are not. Maybe better to change separators with `|`

Comment: @Justinas no, the line must start in this way, the "," among characters in "()" dont' have be to considered... this is the regExp "
var regex_virgola= /\,\(/gm;" that matches those "," but i don't know how to reproduce the desidere output

Comment: You need a regex to only match the commas which are not in parentheses then you can use split()

Comment: @Alex i have edited the question with regExp that i would use, but how can i obtain the desidered output? see one moment the edites that i do to question

Comment: i have edited the question , i had tried with regExp to match the indices in which match occurs, but the structure of indice given to me is empty@Justinas @Alex

Answer (score 1):

With the regex you can use the [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method of string which will result in an array.
To create the output you can join() the array with `\n` to create the line breaks.

```js
var output = "Query Response #1:,(0008,0005) CS ssxssx,(00,00) DA dsdww,(w,e) TM dww,(20)sxs";


var regex_virgola = /\,\(/gm;

const res = output.split(regex_virgola);
console.log(res.join("\n("));
```

```css
Query Response #1: (0008, 0005) CS ssxssx (00, 00) DA dsdww (w, e) TM dww (20)sxs
```

Comment: thank you very much, but your code eliminate the first "( ", launching the code snippet @Alex

Comment: @RexNedved9 as a hotfix you can add it behind your newline `"\n("`

Comment: you're welcome :) If you think it was helpful, mark it as accepted the button below up-/downvote.